# Ordered List within a Table Cell using Textile

Tags: html, redmine, textile

I've got a [Wiki](http://redmine.org) which uses Textile to markup text. I'm trying to put a list within a table cell, and I can't seem to figure out how. I'm trying to replicate the following HTML in Textile:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Cell One</td>
    <td>
        Cell Two
        <ol>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
        </ol>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Tried a lot of things but couldn't get anything to work. Is it possible todo this without using <li> HTML tags in Textile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem currently in RubyMine. I have a solution that works on [Textile](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/), perhaps it helps you:

```
|Cell One|Cell Two ==<ol><li>Lorem</li>
<li>Ipsum</li></ol>== test|
```

It doesn't work in Redmine, though :(